# azure terraform linux aci connector CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: azure, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-service-principal

I hope someone can help me to solve this issue.

I am trying to deploy an Azure kubernetes cluster with a virtual node, the terraform apply runs and provisions all the nodepools correctly but the aci connector pod throws an CrashLoopBackOff with the following error:

```
level=fatal msg="error creating provider: error setting up network: error while looking up subnet: GET 403: 403 Forbidden\nERROR CODE: AuthorizationFailed\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": \"AuthorizationFailed\",\n    \"message\": \"The client does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read' over scope /aks-dev-vnet/subnets/aks-dev-aci' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.\"\n  }\n}\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
```

i do have the following configurations in my terraform:

Virtual network and subnets:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_virtual_network" {
  address_space       = [""]
  location            = var.location
  name                = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
}

# System Pool Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "system_pool_subnet" {
  address_prefixes     = [""]
  name                 = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-system-pool"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_virtual_network.name
}

# System Pool Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "linux_pool_subnet" {
  address_prefixes     = [""]
  name                 = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-linux-pool"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_virtual_network.name
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "aci_subnet" {
  address_prefixes     = [""]
  name                 = "aks-${var.environment}-${var.region}-aci"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_virtual_network.name
  delegation {
    name = "aci-subnet"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}
```

Service principal configurations:

```
resource "azuread_application" "aks_application" {
  display_name = "azure-app-${var.environment}-${var.region}-principle"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "aks_service_principle" {
  application_id = azuread_application.aks_application.application_id
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "main" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principle.id
}

# Grant AKS cluster access to join AKS subnet
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "linux_subnet_aci" {
  scope                = azurerm_subnet.linux_pool_subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principle.id
}

# Grant AKS cluster access to join AKS subnet
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "system_subnet_aci" {
  scope                = azurerm_subnet.system_pool_subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principle.id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aci_subnet" {
  scope                = azurerm_subnet.aci_subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principle.id
}
```

and my cluster configuration:

```
default_node_pool {
    name                 = "systempool"
    vm_size              = "Standard_D2_V2"
    orchestrator_version = data.azurerm_kubernetes_service_versions.current.latest_version
    zones                = [1]
    enable_auto_scaling  = true
    min_count            = 1
    max_count            = 2
    os_disk_size_gb      = 64
    type                 = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    vnet_subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.system_pool_subnet.id
    node_labels = {
      "nodepool-type" = "System"
      "environment"   = "${var.environment}"
      "nodepoolOS"    = "linux"
      "app"           = "System"
      "nodepool" = "systempool00"
    }
    upgrade_settings {
      max_surge = "10%"
    }


  }
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned.id]
  }
  kubelet_identity {
    client_id = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned.client_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned.principal_id
    user_assigned_identity_id = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_assigned.id
  }
  oidc_issuer_enabled = true

  # Add On Profile
  aci_connector_linux {
    subnet_name = azurerm_subnet.aci_subnet.name
  }
```

At this point i know that i should user the service principle in the cluster configuration:

```
#  service_principal {
#    client_id     = azuread_application.aks_application.application_id
#    client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.main.value
#  }
```

but when i try to enable it, i get the error that only one identity can be enabled (identity or service principal).
In my specific case i need the identity to be configured for dns permission for another bit of the platform.

when i get the error in the aci connector. The object id that is referencing, is the managed identity that get automatically created, and the issue is that that managed identity doesnt have permission to perform actions on the subnet.

I am really confused at this point and i cannot think about any workaround this configurations to grant permission to the aci managed identity and also have my identity enabled.

Can anyone shade some light here please?..if my query is not 100% clear just let me know and i can provide more informations.

thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: To resolve the issue, Try manually assign the "Network Contributor" role to the auto-generated managed identity of the ACI connector for the ACI subnet. This action will ensure the necessary permissions are granted after the initial deployment through the Azure portal or CLI, while maintaining the functionality of the user-assigned managed identity for DNS and the ACI connector @NaydenVan

Comment: @VinayB thank you for your answer. Yes, if i add manually that configuration to the aci managed identity from the portal, the aci connector pod start running. But i have no idea how i could possibly managed this in terraform

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Terraform Linux ACI connector CrashLoopBackOff Issue

The issue with the ACI connector in your Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) deployment stems from the managed identity's permissions to access the subnet. It appears you're using a user-assigned managed identity for the AKS cluster and are trying to apply role assignments to provide the required permissions for network activities. Nevertheless, the ACI connector needs distinct permissions to engage with the designated subnet, and the error suggests that these permissions have not been correctly established.

I tried a updated terraform configuration with changes as per the requirement and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

***My Terraform configuration:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azuread" {}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "kubernetes_resource_group" {
  name     = "testvksb-rg"
  location = "East US2"
}

resource "azuread_application" "aks_application" {
  display_name = "aksApp"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "aks_service_principal" {
  client_id                    = azuread_application.aks_application.client_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "aks_sp_password" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principal.id
  end_date_relative    = "8760h" # 1 year
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_virtual_network" {
  name                = "myVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "system_pool_subnet" {
  name                 = "systemSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_virtual_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.240.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "aci_subnet" {
  name                 = "aciSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_virtual_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.241.0.0/16"]
  delegation {
    name = "aciDelegation"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aci_subnet_contributor" {
  scope                = azurerm_subnet.aci_subnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_service_principal.id
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster" {
  name                = "vkAKSCluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.kubernetes_resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "myaksdns"

  default_node_pool {
    name           = "default"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.system_pool_subnet.id
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = azuread_application.aks_application.application_id
    client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.aks_sp_password.value
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "azure"
    service_cidr      = "10.10.0.0/16"
    dns_service_ip    = "10.10.0.10"
   // docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
  }
  
 aci_connector_linux {
    subnet_name = azurerm_subnet.aci_subnet.name
  }
}
```

***deployment successfull:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]